# Camera partial crash in CM13

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, sony-xperia-sp

I am running CM13 Android 6.0 on Xperia SP(codename huashan). After upgrading to CM13, I am unable to capture images using the camera. When I open up the camera app and click an image it gets stuck and no further operations are not possible. Also the captured image never gets saved even if the save location is SD card or device memory. Is there any way to fix this or is this a known bug with CM13 for my device.

I have tried other camera apps as well but that did not solve the issue

Comment: We can't really help fixing nightly/alpha build ROM (and it's [off-topic as per nightly build ROM policy](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/recommendation-for-questions-pertaining-to-a-problem-specific-to-a-nightly-build)), report it to the developer, or wait until it's been fixed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to alpha build of custom ROM, which is never be intended for daily purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to the xda page for this version
http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-sp/orig-development/6-0-cyanogenmod-13-0-t3238355

[image: Snapshot of xda page that shows this is currently work in progress]